# Can't see textures in render mode only

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

I downloaded a free 3D model, it is a Blender file.
https://free3d.com/3d-model/house-10c2-71388.html

There is a strange problem - the model is pink, which usually means that the texture is missing, but in material mode I can see the textures. And also in the node editor a see a big list of textures.

[image]

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm they are in the file by checking them in the UV/Image Editor? I usually see a thumbnail beside their name when looking at them in the list, and then can see the full image in the editor.

Comment: " [...] but in material mode I can see the textures." Are you sure? For you're in solid mode, not in texture mode. The colors you're able to see on the house are only the viewport colors set in the materials tab, not the textures itself.

Comment: The fact that you can browse through the image textures listed in the dropdown of the Image Texture node doesn't necessarily mean there are any images found, those are image texture datablocks used by Blender to store settings for that texture and a link to the file (also as there aren't any textures thumbnails in that dropdown looks like files aren't found). So check if Blender can actually find those files as stated above.